# Short story - AI wakes up, takes over when mathematician discovers how to factor products of large primes

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

Dystopian short story - an agent on Earth, reads that a mathematician has a method to factor products of two huge primes, so he tries to contact him and suppress knowledge, but it's too late. The AI wakes up, takes over the world, and agent goes back to his parallel universe, which is ruled by sympathetic AI.

Comment: Do you mean a method to factor huge **composite** numbers **efficiently**? It's possible to factor any number given enough computing power and time, but doing it in a reasonable amount of time with modest computing power is very difficult.

Comment: That's the point of the story- the algorithm is so efficient it catalyzes an AI becoming so capable it rapidly takes over the world-and lets us know this has happened before in countless parallel universes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That sounds like "Antibodies" by Charles Stross. It's in his collection *Toast* (you can download it from Charles' webpage, [here](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/fiction/toast/toast-intro.html) and read the story [here](https://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/fiction/toast/toast.html#antibodies))

> Protagonist finds out a mathematician has just proved P=NP. He and his partners, spies for some unknown authority, try to suppress the information - at first the reader has no idea why - but fail. They decide to escape instead, and just barely make it as AI quickly takes over human society; there's a scene where they sneak past security officers wearing unusual earpieces who are clearly being remote controlled. As they escape into a parallel universe, the protagonists reflect on their good luck in coming from one of the few timelines *not* taken over by AI - but it becomes obvious to the reader that they are also under control, and have been brainwashed into believing that *their* AI overlord is the good one.

Comment: This answer would be much better if you gave some indication of why you thought this was a match.

Comment: Fair enough, I've edited my answer to add plot details.

Comment: We can assume that the plot summary is your own, since there is no attribution?

Comment: Instead of mentioning just one collection containing that story, it would be more helpful to more users to link to the [full list](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?92114).

Comment: Yup, that's it, thanks!

Comment: I had a brain hiccup, I meant products of large primes.

Comment: Proving P=NP (thus opening a lot of hard interesting problems to be solved by computer in acceptable times) would be much more interesting than "factoring large numbers efficiently" which would be nice but would not help with any other hard problems (technically, factorization is not NP-complete, see also "Integer Factorization" at https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Garden )

Comment: In fact the story says: _“Someone’s come up with a proof that NP-complete problems lie in P! There’s a posting in comp.risks saying they’ve used it to find an O*(n²) [should be O(n²), and note it's not O(n^1000), which would be less exciting] solution to the traveling salesman problem, and it scales! Looks like April First has come early this year, doesn’t it?”_ Yeah that would blow anyone's mind. Read also: [NP-complete Problems and Physical Reality](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/npcomplete.pdf) by Scott Aaronson.

Comment: _"and have been brainwashed into believing that their AI overlord is the good one"_ That conclusion is wrong. In fact, the local AI overlord is so messed up because of the prevailing religion. From the text: _That’s because we’re lucky. If you believe in reincarnation, the idea of creating a machine that can trap a soul stabs a dagger right at the heart of your religion. Buddhist worlds that develop high technology, Zoroastrian worlds: these world-lines tend to survive. Judaeo-Christian-Islamic ones generally don’t._